# How to store ImageMagick output into Bash variable (and then use it)?

Tags: bash, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I use ImageMagick and need to do conditional resize of images.

For that I store results of the `identify` tool into variables.

```
$infile='test.jpg'
width=$(identify -ping -format %w $infile)
height=$(identify -ping -format %h $infile)
```

But before resizing I want to do some transformations that change image size: `-trim` and `-shave`. So I need to calculate image size in between of trimming and resizing. And I'd like to do the trim operation only once to make a little optimization.

So, I'd like:

1. to do trim and shave
2. store *[binary]* result in a variable (for example: `$data`)
3. pass `$data` variable value as input to `identify` tool and store its result for conditional resizing
4. pass `$data` to `convert` tool and finish processing

Something like this:

```
data=$(convert logo: -shave 1x1 gif:-)
width=$(echo $data | identify -ping -format %w gif:-)
echo $data | convert -resize "$width"
```

But `echo` doesn't work as needed.

P. S. `convert` and `identify` are [tools from ImageMagick suite](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-tools.php)

Comment: Shell variables are not binary data safe. They cannot contain NUL for example. You cannot store raw binary in them.

Comment: As you are using `bash`, you can make another optimisation and avoid calling `identify` twice, once to read the width and once to read the height, like this `read w h < <(identify -ping -format "%w %h" wizard:)`

Comment: Thank you, @MarkSetchell.  I've never used Bash before, so it looks like hell. But I'm trying.

Comment: You can just run the contained part on its own to see the output that I feed into the `read` command. Run this to see the width and height of the built-in wizard file, or change `wizard:` to the name of one of your own images... `identify -ping -format "%w %h" wizard:`

Comment: Thanks! Output redirection and other bash features breaks my mind more than IM syntax. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bash can not store blobs of data that may contain `NULL` terminating characters. But you can convert the data to [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), and use ImageMagick's [`fd:`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#fd) protocol.

```
# Store base64-ed image in `data'
data=$(convert logo: -shave 1x1 gif:- | base64)
# Pass ASCII data through decoding, and pipe to stdin file descriptor
width=$(base64 --decode <<< $data | identify -ping -format %w fd:0)
base64 --decode <<< $data | convert -resize "$width" -
```

Comment: Nice approach - have my vote! For anyone else reading this, you can also just use a hyphen (`-`) for `stdin` instead of `fd:0`.

Comment: Ah yes, last line is missing the '-' symbol. Will update answer

Comment: There is an error even with '-'. `base64 --decode <<< $data | convert -resize "$width" -` in OS X 10.8 (IM 6.9.1-4 Q16 x86_64) produces: http://pastebin.com/1MzVF3XN And `width=$(base64 --decode <<< $data | identify -ping -format %w fd:0)` in Ubuntu 14.04.2 (IM 6.7.7-10 2014-03-06 Q16) produces: http://pastebin.com/hwLtubUG I deleted my previous comment because of bad formatting.

Comment: Sorry, it was stupid. Just needed to add output filename in the last line: `base64 --decode <<< $data | convert -resize "$width" - result.jpg` But what is wrong with Ubuntu? Strange version of base64 utility?

Comment: Are you definitely using `bash`? You need to be using `bash` in order to use `<<<` and `$(...)`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes, it's bash. And I found a solution for Ubuntu, described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9580720/4834319), [here](http://www.codedisqus.com/0iSqVPgVej/decode-base64-invalid-input.html), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15490765/4834319). `-i` flag added to `base64 --decode` solves the problem. Thanks to all!